# How to find the implicit function of $\,\mathrm dx/\mathrm dt=y+y^2-x^3=y+P_2(x,y)\;?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, implicit-function-theorem

[image]

> How to find the implicit function of $\,\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=y+y^2-x^3=y+P_2(x,y)\;\;?$

I am facing difficulty to find the implicit function in the given example (the picture is attached).
How can we find the implicit function ?

Comment: Please use $Mathjax$ for equations

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @ARahman, since $y^2+y-x^3=0$, we get that $$y=\phi(x)=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^3}}2$$ Now, you can use the following Taylor's Formula with Peano's form of remainder : $$\sqrt{1+h}=1+\dfrac h2-\dfrac{h^2}8+\dfrac{h^3}{16}-\dfrac{5h^4}{128}+o(h^4)$$ with $\,h=4x^3\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Your task is not to find some ODE solution, but the curve where the right side is zero for $x,y\approx 0$.
$$
0=y+y^2-x^3
$$
As $y^2\ll |y|$, the only balance of terms is for $0\approx y-x^3$. Now refine this first approximation by treating
$$
y_{new}=x^3-y_{old}^2
$$
as fixed-point iteration
$$
y=x^3-x^6\\
y=x^3-x^6+2x^9+O(x^{12})\\
y=x^3-x^6(1-x^3+2x^6)^2+O(x^{15})
$$
etc.